# Gas or Electric for a Zombie Apocalypse

Tags: apocalypse, electricity, zombies, power-sources, gas

This question is referring to tools, like chainsaws and weedwhackers.
Gas would be easier to get, being a liquid form that can be stockpiled, but gas tools are loud and leave fumes.
Meanwhile, electricity is good because of how quiet it is, the ability to be made in a generator, and batteries can be stockpiled, but generators require gas to operate, electricity runs out quicker, and is somewhat less durable.

What should be the primary power source in my story?

Comment: I'll be honest, if it's a Zombie Apocalypse -making sure my Lawn is neat and tidy and avoiding HOA fines isn't very high on my list of priorities. Can you expand on what the tools are being used for - because Petrol vs Electric have different properties that make them better for certain applications *and without knowing the application, it's hard to make a recommendation*

Comment: To second @TheDemonLord comment, we need more information.  Is this about someone stockpiling in anticipation of an apocalypse or scavenging in the aftermath?  Very importantly, where is this occurring - with solar panels it makes a huge difference whether this is occurring in Florida or Alaska?

Comment: Hello @Mace19, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. For future reference, we help people create and consistently use the rules governing an imaginary world of their own making. We specifically don't help people tell stories (see [help/on-topic]). This question falls square into the story-telling side of things unless you can explain how the question relates to story-independent rules. This question is 100% dependent on your story (which is a reason to close questions: too story-based) because which is better depends on [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).

Comment: Hello @Mace19. The issue with your question is that it is much too open-ended and depends a lot on the rest of your world. And, remember this: zombie apocalypse worlds are never about the _worlds_ , but about the _story_ you play out in them. So whatever you need for the story to work, that is how the world is, and then you have to adapt to that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends largely on time frame. Gas (both diesel and gasoline) spoils relatively quickly without additives and after a year or so starts to become harmful to burn in engines. So in your zombie apocalypse if you're in the opening weeks after the apocolypse happens gas will be relatively abundant and gas powered tools are likely going to be more common. If it has been a few years unless you are able to produce your own fuel it's more likely you will be using battery powered tools.

Also Gas is hard to make and is a fairly finite resource in an apocalypse. If your survivors have some form of compound they might have solar panels or rigged up a windmill to power battery operated tools. They don't even need to be commercial size installations, you can make a windmill that can charge car batteries out of a car alternator and some creative use of bike parts. You may be able to distill ethanol and run some tools on that but I can't imagine that's ideal either

Answer (score 0):

Where does the electricity come from?

If your electricity comes from diesel-burning generators, I would have thought using the fuel directly in your chainsaw would be more efficient.

If your electricity comes from another source, such as an Old-World power station that still operates, then it would make more sense to use that, if portability isn't a concern.

You could even try renewables - a cursory Google suggests pre-industrial windmills can produce power into the tens of kilowatts, more than enough for lightbulbs and power tools, provided you can get a decent alternator.